# DF2018 meetup group picture

Tags: discussion

[image]

Thank you everyone for attending, it was nice to meet all of you. Hope to see you again in other events!

Comment: Thank you for sharing!

Comment: I sure enjoyed meeting everyone in person!

Comment: I enjoyed a lot, helped me put faces to names. :) Thanks glls and codey for hosting it. Much appreciated.

Comment: Great picture! If anybody could digitize the names into the picture it would help more people to put faces to the names ;)

Comment: Just wish I could have been there at DF. Hope everyone had a good journey home from DF.

Comment: sorry I missed it, was dealing with a P0 PROD bug and got kicked out of Moscone.

Comment: Sorry I missed it as well.

Comment: This is amazing. Sorry I missed it - was just too tired after presenting all my sessions. Hope to see you all again at either TDX19 or DF19

Comment: Looking good peeps!  Sorry I missed it - next year, I'm in!